# Use maven to compare local file with revision

Tags: java, maven, svn

I have two types of files: A and B. B files are output of A files. Both types of files are under svn control. When you commit them, I need to make sure that the B files are the same svn version as the A files, since i do not want the B files to be outdated. I can generate the B files only manually, and any change done to A files must result in generating B files. Is there any way to compare the svn and local files by version?? I wish to stop the maven build if the files don't match the top criterias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to take a look at the [maven-enforcer-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) where you have to create an own enforcer rule which can check the above.